# Postman testing: How do I add information to the results of my tests when I export it?

Tags: postman

**Postman ver 6:**

How do I add information to the results of my tests when I export it? I though console.log would do it but it didn't.

This is when I'm in the test runner and I click export?
[image]

```
pm.test("Address is valid", function () {
    var jsonObj = data.Candidates[0].Codes.DpvMatchCode;
    console.log(Object.keys(jsonObj)[0]);
    pm.expect(Object.keys(jsonObj)[0]).to.be.oneOf(["Y","D","S"]);
    pm.expect(data.Candidates[0].Result.delivery_line_2).to.include(" BOX ");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Postman doesn't support that, I think your best bet will be to use [Newman](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/command_line_integration_with_newman/) to run a collection and capture the output to a file:

```
newman run google_collection

Google

→ Drive - Set access token
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token [200 OK, 627B, 393ms]
√  Status code is 200

→ List all files
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files [200 OK, 17.36KB, 639ms]
┌
│ 'test drive#fileList'
└

→ Search for file by name
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=name="00P0H00001EXpn8" [200 OK, 660B, 340ms]
```

Note that in the 2nd request the following output comes from `console.log`:

```
┌
│ 'test drive#fileList'
└
```

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish since doing might get messing trying to parse everything out but this might be your best bet. You could potentially also use some sort of custom html reporter but that also might be messy and definitely need to use newman.